# Is is possible to go parameterized variant with python's dataclasses?

Tags: python

Python's dataclasses is pretty cool, I've read [some tutorial](https://gist.github.com/masahitojp/eff33a4c0ac3293d4a901b580a9907eb), and most of them  look like

```py
import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass
class User:
    name: str
    age: int = 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    u = User("taro", 32)


    match u:
        case User(name, age):
            print(f"{name}, {age}")
```

For people from OCaml world, I was wondering if maybe we could do parameterized variant like things with `dataclasses`?

```ml
#
type 'a mtype =
  | Empty
  | Cons of 'a * 'a mtype
;;

# let (musage: int mtype) = Cons (1, Cons (2, Empty));;
val musage : int mtype = Cons (1, Cons (2, Empty))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OCaml, `mtype` alone is not a type. You could think of it as a function over types, like `mtype : type -> type`, in the sense that given a type `'a`, it will monomorphise in a concrete type `'a mtype`. This requires "special" syntax because, in OCaml, operating on types like that cannot be done by any function anyhow. In Python, on the other hand, there is absolutely no such restriction: everything is an object, *including types*. So really creating a generic dataclass is as easy as:

```py
def User(ty):
    @dataclass
    class User:
        name: str
        age: ty
    return User
```

Of course, this solution may not be completely satisfactory. For instance, one thing you may dislike is that it will produce ugly class names:

```
>>> User(int)
<class '__main__.User.<locals>.User'>
>>> User(int)("hello", 3)
User.<locals>.User(name='hello', age=3)
>>>
```

However, with Python's flexibility, it shouldn't be hard for you circumvent this kind of issues.

---

Besides that, as @Chris pointed out, Python is not a statically typed language (and not functional either), so beware of just translating literally OCaml code, in the sense that having generic dataclass is something I have never encountered before, probably because it's not that useful in Python.